# How to specify the location of my figures?

Tags: floats, templates, lncs

I'm writing with the LNCS template on Overleaf, but one of my figures keeps displaying somewhere way behind where I explain it. Is there a way to specify where I want it to display?

```
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=12cm]{Replay.eps}
    \caption{Buffer Size for Experience Replay}
    \label{Replay}
\end{figure}
```

---

The figure is inserted to where the red arrow points to, but shows up two pages later.

[image]

Comment: Can you show how it looks like and explain where exactly you'd like it to be?

Comment: Does it have to that wide? Figures "float" in Latex documents and strictly specifying a position, while not impossible, is not recommended. Instead, you should avoid large figures (this one, but also the ones before if any).

Comment: Have you checked [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text)?

Comment: With your float placement specification it appear in text where  figure is inserted, if there is enough space for it. Other wise it is moved (float) to the top of the next page.

Comment: @antshar Thank you! I just added a snapshot.

Comment: @Zarko Yeah ... but it shows up two pages later ... T_T

Comment: The figure is too big to fit in any of the specified locations -- `hbt`.  That automatically pushes it off until the end of the document.  Add `p` to the options and it will then be put on the next available page.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want your figure to "float" - aka be placed wherever Latex feels like it should go - don't use a floating environment like figure. You can use `/captionof` to create a figure which will be numbered and appear in the list of figures.

```
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=18cm]{3DQN.eps}
    \captionof{figure}[How our figure appears in the List of Figures]{Caption of our Figure}
    \label{3DQN}
\end{minipage}
```